# ORA-00932 if collection used in recursive CTE in where clause

Tags: oracle, collections, oracle11g, recursive-query, ora-00932

I have recursive CTE with column of collection type (`sys.ku$_vcnt` is used here because it is built-in, problem can be reproduced for any collection type). When the collection column is used in recursive part of CTE in `where` clause, query fails with `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got SYS.KU$_VCNT` error.

This is minimized example, in real case the collection content is inspected in `where` clause. Any occurence of collection seems enough for query to fail - for instance not null check as shown in following example:

```
with r (l, dummy_coll, b) as (
  select 1 as l, sys.ku$_vcnt(), null from dual
  union all
  select l + 1
       , r.dummy_coll
       , case when r.dummy_coll is not null then 'not null' else 'null' end as b
  from r
  where l < 5 and r.dummy_coll is not null
)
select * from r;
```

If `and r.dummy_coll is not null` is removed from `where` clause, the query succeeds. Occurence of collection in `select` clause is not problem (the `b` column shows the collection is actually not null).

Why does not it work and how to force Oracle to see collection column from previous recursion level in `where` clause?

Reproduced in Oracle 11 and Oracle 18 ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5b6dcceac281b42c602029dcacfdc744)).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that looks like a bug to me.  A scalar select seems to be a workaround. Would that work in your case?

```
SQL> with r (l, dummy_coll, b) as (
  2    select 1 as l, sys.ku$_vcnt(), null from dual
  3    union all
  4    select l + 1
  5         , r.dummy_coll
  6         , case when r.dummy_coll is not null then 'not null' else 'null' end as b
  7    from r
  8    where l < 5 and ( select r.dummy_coll from dual ) is not null
  9  )
 10  select * from r;

L,DUMMY_COLL,B
1,KU$_VCNT(),
2,KU$_VCNT(),not null
3,KU$_VCNT(),not null
4,KU$_VCNT(),not null
5,KU$_VCNT(),not null
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! Meanwhile I made up workaround `where l < 5 and (cast(multiset(select * from table(r.dummy_coll)) as sys.ku$_vcnt) is not null` which works too, yours is much simpler.

Comment: Since the actual condition was `something not member of r.dummy_coll` (which was successfully replaced by `something not member of (select r.dummy_coll from dual)` thanks to accepted answer), alternative solution is also `something not in (select column_value from table(r.dummy_coll))`. I discovered it a couple of weeks later.